# How to prepare a Cassandra Accessor query only once

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using the [Cassandra Java Driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver). In order to use the `Object Mapper` I have created an `Accessor`.

```
@Accessor
public interface MyAccessor
{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ? AND event_day = ? AND event_time > ? AND event_time < ?")
    Result<MyEvent> getEvents(UUID id, String eventDay, Date eventFromDate, Date eventToDate);
}
```

I use this accessor in a method like this:

```
public List<MyEvent> getEvents(UUID id, String eventDay, Date eventFromDate, Date eventToDate)
    {
        MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(_cassandraDatabaseManager.getSession());

        MyAccessor myAccessor= manager.createAccessor(MyAccessor.class);

        return myAccessor.getEvents(id, eventDay, eventFromDate, eventToDate).all();
    }
```

In my application I call this method multiple times and I receive the following warning in the log:

```
Re-preparing already prepared query SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ? AND event_day = ? AND event_time > ? AND event_time < ?. Please note that preparing the same query more than once is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.
```

What is the best practice to use the `Cassandra Accessor`? Should I create the `Accessor` only once and then cache it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I create the Accessor only once and then cache it?

You should at least cache the `MappingManager`. It caches accessor instances internally, so successive calls to `createAccessor` on the same manager instance will cost you only a hash map lookup. If you want to avoid that lookup, you can cache accessor instances too.

Comment: Thank you. I added the creation of the `MappingManager` inside the CassandraDatabaseManager singleton and everything works great. It is strange that I could not find any info regarding this. There is nothing on this topic in the Datastax documentation.